# codeigniter $qry->result() not working

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

The following codeigniter query everytime is empty. $metas->result() is not fetching datas. If I var_dump the raw query and running in console everything is okay.

```
$metas=$this->db->query("SELECT id,meta_description, meta_title, meta_keywords, template, google_tracking, user_option
                         FROM domains
                         WHERE NAME ='$this->domain_name'");


return $metas->result();
```

Comment: have you column called NAME ?

Comment: it called NAME or name ?

Comment: @fefe you shouldn't put it in capitals then. It defies the holy sql name conventions

Comment: this seems to be the problem the uppercase

Comment: @fefe officially you should even put prefixes before the column names that refer to the table. So f.e do_name, do_id, etc. In that way you never run into the "... is ambiguous" issue. However nobody really does this, including me actually... Too lazy haha

Comment: Yes I have to refactor a bit my queries

Comment: @fefe true, also refactor it to prevent sql injections. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 WHERE name ='$this->domain_name'");
```

Capitals it dfies the whole sql

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was improper query string

Answer (score 2):

Not only put in lowercase because of the naming conventions but also use binding to prevent sql injection:

```
$sql = "SELECT id,meta_description, meta_title, meta_keywords, template, google_tracking, user_option FROM domains WHERE name= ?";

$this->db->query($sql, array($this->domain_name));
```

CodeIgniter only excapes variables when you pass the variables as binds